# Configure IntelliJ to work with Java 14 and records

Tags: java, intellij-idea, editor, java-14

I have tried to make IntelliJ work with SDK-14, but I am obviously having problems getting records to work. Since the release date is in March, I would think that the good people at Jetbrains are close to having a version that works with SDK-14. I need to run SDK 14 with --enable-preview. I have googled for a couple of days without any luck.

I had some luck with Sublime, but I miss code-completion. If there are other options, please feel free to mention them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE**: The first 2020.1 EAP with Records support [is released](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/01/intellij-idea-2020-1-eap/).

IntelliJ IDEA support for Records (JEP 359) is work in progress and will be available in 2020.1 release (EAP for this version should start in January 2020, release is planned for March-April 2020).

Related tickets:

- [IDEA-228462](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-228462) Rename record components
- [IDEA-229318](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-229318) Adapt C-style array declaration for record component
- [IDEA-229706](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-229706) Formatter for Java 14 Records
- [IDEA-229841](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-229841) Records: report redundant constructors
- [IDEA-229842](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-229842) Convert compact constructor to canonical
- [IDEA-229843](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-229843) Change signature refactoring for records
- [IDEA-229844](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-229844) Quick documentation support for record components
- [IDEA-229921](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-229921) .class stubs for JEP 359 "Records"
- [IDEA-223110](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-223110) Implement parser for JEP 359: Records (Preview) in Java
- [IDEA-228460](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-228460) Error highlighting for records
- [IDEA-229297](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-229297) Add Java 14 records to "New Java class" view
- [IDEA-229300](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-229300) Code completion support for records
- [IDEA-229320](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-229320) Heap pollution warning for records
- [IDEA-229792](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-229792) Support record declaration in complete statement
- [IDEA-229795](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-229795) Support record creation on UML diagrams
- [IDEA-229796](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-229796) Create record from usage
- [IDEA-229889](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-229889) Highlight usages for Record components
- [IDEA-229694](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-229694) Generate constructor for records: suggest generation of compact and canonical constructors
- [UX-1087](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/UX-1087) Add icon for java Record

Comment: Great! So when I check for updates I need to select Early Access Program?

Comment: Yes, EAP stands for Early Access Program. Placeholder page: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2020.1+latest+builds. https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/ will also point to the EAP version when it's available.